# How can i pass a "=" sign to cli parameter with argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I want the argparse cli parameter to use "=" sign when i'm giving the list of the arguments with a space between them.

For example:

`--repos= repo1 repo2 repo3`

but when i'm giving the parameters in this way i'm getting the following exception
"error: unrecognized arguments: repo1 repo2 repo3"

Is there a way to pass the '=' to the parameter?

Comment: Typically this would be `--repos repo1 --repos repo2 --repos repo3`, then you can use `action='append'`. Or do `--repos=repo1,repo2,repo3` or `--repos='repo1 repo2 repo3'` then split it in e.g. a custom `type`.

Comment: drop the '=' and use a `nargs` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the '=' sign to the parameter by enclosing the argument that follows the '=' sign in quotes. For example:

--repos="repo1 repo2 repo3"

This will pass "repo1 repo2 repo3" as a single argument to the --repos option.